# The asynchronous method starts AsyncCallback in the current thread (main thread)

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, sockets, asynchronous

There is a server of TcpListener class. It accepts incoming connections using the BeginAcceptTcpClient (AsyncCallback, Object) method.

The code is written in the example MSDN

```
public static ManualResetEvent tcpClientConnected = 
    new ManualResetEvent(false);

public static void DoBeginAcceptTcpClient(TcpListener 
    listener)
{
    while(true)
    {
        tcpClientConnected.Reset();
        Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a connection...");
        listener.BeginAcceptTcpClient(
            new AsyncCallback(DoAcceptTcpClientCallback), 
            listener);
        tcpClientConnected.WaitOne();
    }
}
public static void DoAcceptTcpClientCallback(IAsyncResult ar) 
{
    TcpListener listener = (TcpListener) ar.AsyncState;
    TcpClient client = listener.EndAcceptTcpClient(ar);
    Console.WriteLine("Client connected completed");
    tcpClientConnected.Set();
    while(true)
    {
         //Receiving messages from the client
    }
}
```

The problem is that the DoAcceptTcpClientCallback (IAsyncResult ar) method **sometimes** starts executing in the current thread (main), not the new one, and blocks it (main). Because of this, the following connections can not be received.
Please help to understand why not create a thread for this method

Comment: You haven't shown us, but I'd imagine that `//Receiving messages from the client` is for some reason switching back to using *synchronous* API calls. Don't do that. Once you go async (in some manner that doesn't involve creating threads) you don't know what thread you'll be running on - so you should only run for as long as it takes for you to dispatch the next async method and then return.

Comment: First, why aren't you using [AcceptTcpClientAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.accepttcpclientasync%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) ? It's available in all supported .NET versions and makes asynchronous programming a lot easier.

Comment: Second `asynchronous` doesn't mean `different thread`. It means that your thread won't block waiting for a response. IO operations may not even need a separate thread as IO in Windows is always asynchronous at the driver level. The API *emulates* blocking to make single-threaded programming easier

Answer (score 4):

Yes, as you've discovered, [you're not guaranteed that your `AsyncCallback` is called on a new thread](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iasyncresult.completedsynchronously(v=vs.110).aspx). Basically if an asynchronous operation completes so quickly that the callback can be run synchronously from the same thread, it will.

That happens when by the time `BeginXXX` calls want to return in the old async model, the thing you're waiting for to happen has already happened, e.g. in your case a connection, so to prevent an unnecessary context switch, it sets `IAsyncResult.CompletedSynchronously` to true and executes your callback synchronously which in your example infinitely blocks the thread in the `while (true)` loop, never letting it return from the `BeginAcceptTcpClient` call.

You should account for that scenario in your callback method by continuing to remain asynchronous and returning quickly.

Also, look into using [async/await](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/async), they make asynchronous programming much easier.